# HP Probook 6550b Specifications query

Tags: specifications

I have a HP Probook 6550b but something is confusing me about its specifications.

On the internet you can see an AMD graphics option but I haven't seen such option in mine, there is only an Intel HD Graphics option.

I would like to know if there is a solution or is it that it's not supported?

Answer (score 0):

HP generally  has several models with different options for a given name.

What you must look at is the product number, that look like "LG732EA#UUG" for example. It gives you the exact variant of the product (the part #UUG is not really needed it only give the keyboard variant and may not even exists in the US).

Searching with this product number of HP web sites should lead you to the exact specifications of your product.

For the 6550b there's model with AMD graphic and models with only intel graphics.

Comment: don't forget to mark the question as solved (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so it doesn't stuck in the unanswered queue.